# Cannot count rows with special character in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has 4 columns. I want to count number of rows in which the value '\N' occurs. The entire dataframe's columns have dtype:objects. In the example below, the count would be 1 (1 row where \N occurs).

**df.episode**
[image]

This is the code which didn't work:

```
len(filter(lambda df: r'\N' in str(df.episode), rows))

Output Error: NameError: name 'rows' is not defined
```

How would I define rows? I am not sure what it is referring to.

Comment: What is `rows`? Does it exist as a object? You also when working with pandas and frames want to be avoiding things like `len`,`filter` etc... I suspect you're after something like: `df.eq(r'\N').any(1).sum()`

Comment: Thank you for this. I now get a number with your code. So, does your code basically count the numbers of rows in which \N occurs? What does the .any(1) exactly mean?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to convert value \N in the entire dataframe with np.Nan?

Comment: Are you loading the file from a delimited format? If so, then look at: the `na_values` parameter for something like: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: The `.any(1)` looks for any `True` boolean value across the row instead of the column - so in effect, it's a filter for any row that has any column that matches `\N`... You can replace those by doing `df.replace(r'\N', np.nan, inplace=True)` if you can't do it on load using the `na_values` argument.

Comment: worked magic! thanks

Comment: I'm trying to find you a really good dupe which I'm sure covers all these points... if not - I'll write you up an answer if you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter rows by looking for columns which contain the character `\N` I assume.

If I look at your `DataFrame` you can do the following to get the rows back which match:

```
df[df.episodeNumber.str.contains(r'\\N') | df.seasonNumber.str.contains(r'\\N')]

    tconst      parentTconst    seasonNumber    episodeNumber
2   tt0042889   tt0989125       \N              \N
```

To count the amount of rows which match this condition, you can use `.shape` or `len()`

```
df[df.episodeNumber.str.contains(r'\\N') | df.seasonNumber.str.contains(r'\\N')].shape

len(df[df.episodeNumber.str.contains(r'\\N') | df.seasonNumber.str.contains(r'\\N')])

#Output
(1, 4)
1
```

Shape returns the shape of your dataframe, in this case (#rows, #columns)

**Note**
I added a backslash `\` before `\N`, we need to literally look for `\N`, only one backslash will in this case function as escape character, so we need to add a second when we want an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

Import `numpy` and `pandas` libraries first.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Create dataframe now, copied sample data from OP's post and ran following command to create a df.

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
```

1st solution: To count rows for `\N` taking inspiration from @Jon Clements comments.

```
df.eq(r'\N').any(1).sum()
```

2nd solution: To your 2nd question to replace `\N` to `NaN` try following.

```
df['seasonNumber']=np.where(df.seasonNumber=='\\N',np.nan,df.seasonNumber)
df
```